# Export compiled php (sessions-related) page as html to be reused as cached version

Tags: php

I have a massive **php script** that allows me to **generate the sidebar menu according to the permissions** given to the individual user. These permissions mainly come from **`$_SESSION`** and from **PHP functions verifications**.

The sidebar menu is always present in every page, so the problem is that this script re-works every time a page in my dashboard is changed. The problem is especially the fact that the page this way now *takes 7-9 seconds to be opened*.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

1. script is launched only one time at login
2. the sidebar menu is compiled and saved as HTML in a separate file (i.g. /user/1/menu.html)
3. all the following times, until login/logout, the menu that is included is the static HTML version and not the PHP script

I tried with cURL, `file_get_contents()`, `fopen()` and everything - but what Is retrieved is the PHP code, and not the compiled version.

Do you have any ideas on how I can get this solved? I simply would like to retrieve the compiled version and save it, so that I can `include()` that file instead of the PHP code every time.

edit: I am also available for front-side solutions, but with jQuery I just get an error 500, maybe because sessions are not taken into consideration in that way.

Thanks in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: if it is an option to include the menu as iframe, you could make use of the browsers caching algorithms with the appropriate HTML headers (find more details in the web, e.g. at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
But also consider wether you want to use caching at all as permissions could change during a session and this could be anything from annoying to the user (that doesn't see a new entry he is now allowed to) to critical (user can use something with a link he is not supposed to "own").

Comment: @cyberbrain I would avodi using an iframe, because I wanted to import the HTML structure as it is. For the permissions changing during the session it wouldn't be a problem, because I would refresh the content of the html-version of the menu server-side